# Sorting of datatables in Bootstrap not working in dynamic data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I implemented datatables as instructed [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

I initialize the table that way but my data is loaded on the fly using AJAX. I have a button that will populate the table when clicked:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'phpfunc/test.php',
    data: {sDate: sDate, eDate: eDate},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      if(result){
          $('#example2 tbody').html(result);
      }else{
        alert(result);
        alert("error");

      }
    }
});
```

And content for test.php is something like this:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo 'Sample Data';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

It populates the table, but my problem is that when I click the sort in column (either descending or ascending), the table's content will be cleared. Does Bootstrap's datatable really work this way or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Its nothing to do with php...

Maybe you will have to re-bind your `.DataSet()` plugin after every ajax call.
For example:

```
success: function(result) {
  if(result){
      $table = $('#example');
      $table.find('tbody').html(result);
      $table.DataTable(); //Rebind
  }else{
    alert(result);
    alert("error");

  }
}
```

I dont know this plugin in particular, but some of them provides rebinding or native data-handling, like:

```
$('#example').DataTable('refresh');
```

But you will have to search it in the documentation yourself. So

Comment: thanks for the response Carlos but it didn't work.. I also search in the plugin's doc.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data to the table through DOM methods, rather than through the DataTables API. There is no listener on the table DOM, so DataTables doesn't automatically know when a new row has been inserted in this manner, and therefore does not know anything about the new data.

Which is why the data clears when you go to "sort" the data. Datatables sorting function runs through the API, not the DOM elements.

More information here: 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: thank you for point that out.. i suspected that was the problem.. but now, i read the docs, most of the examples deals with json type data...in my case I want to process the data first add it to tbody of the table (in DataTables API's way) is it doable?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why you couldn't just format your response to be in json. Working with JSON data is quickly becoming the defacto standard for returning large sets of data. You can find some more info here: http://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/